# Anti-aliasing problem with gtx 1080

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu, antialiasing

I have a big problem of anti-aliasing near the edge of the door . This problem occurs only when i render with GPU ( GTX 1080 ) with the same settings . How can I do ?

Gpu render: [http://i.imgur.com/DXtBwz4.png](https://i.imgur.com/DXtBwz4.png)

[image]

Cpu render: [http://i.imgur.com/oCLmsvK.png](https://i.imgur.com/oCLmsvK.png)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using a build off of Graphical.org? Apparaently the anti-aliasing is a reported bug in those versiosn as they don't fully support the nvidia chipset yet.

For more read here: https://developer.blender.org/T48544